# Many to one relationship with a condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-one

I have two tables, student and teacher, with a relationship ManyToOne. The table structure is as follows

```
student(
    id long,
    student_id string,
    ....
    teacher_id string,
    active boolean
)

teacher(
    id long,
    teacher_id string,
    ....
    active boolean
)
```

I'm using Spring boot and Hibernate. Here when updating an entity, the active column of the existing row in the table will be set to false and a new row will be added with a new id(long) and active as true. That is why there are two id values in each table. The problem here is I have specified the student-teacher relation as many to one in my entity with the foreign key as teacher_id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private String studentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    @Column(name = "active")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean active = true;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private String teacherId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "active")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean active = true;
}
```

But since multiple teachers can occur with the same teacher_id, this fails. Is there any way to give a condition to the relationship to fetch the teacher with active as true? In table, there will be only one teacher with the given id and active as true.

Comment: You should probably include the entity class for `Teacher` as well.

Comment: Added Teacher entity @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: "multiple teachers can occur with the same teacher_id" -> that should not be possible. it defeats the entire purpose of an id.

Comment: The primary key of Teacher entity is id, not teacher_id. The id will change when the entity gets updated. And the student entity is mapped to the teacher_id not to the id.

Comment: @Nipun which makes no sense, since there are/can be duplicates for that "id", you'll never know what teacher your student is actually mapped to

Comment: @Stultuske Just clarifying one thing, if I'm updating the teacher, the id will increment, but teacher_id remains the same. The question here is, is there any possibility to add a condition to the mapping, ie., to add a condition active=true?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across your post. I had the same requirement few months ago and this is what i did..

```
public class Student {

 @Column(name = "teacher_id ")
    private String teacherId;

@ManyToOne
   @JoinFormula(value = "(Select t.id from teacher t where t.teacher_id= teacher_id and t.active=1)"
        )
    private Teacher teacher;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "active")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean active = true;
}
```

This approach works for my case. If there is a better one you can share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There should be no `teacher_id` foreign key field in the `Teacher` entity.  Rather, just use the primary key `id` column instead.  Consider this version of your entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private String studentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    @Column(name = "active")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean active = true;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "active")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean active = true;
}
```

This design should enforce that a given student can be associated with only one teacher (though a given teacher can have multiple students).

Comment: Yeah this will work, but the problem here is whenever I update the teacher entity, a new row will generate(client requirement) with the new id. So if I'm mapping the id, I need to take care of updating the mapped id in student entity also, right?

Comment: No, not really.  Let's say that you fetch a certain teacher, then create a new `Student`.  So long as you assign the relationship from student to teacher, when you `save()` JPA/Hibernate should take care of the rest for you.

Comment: Consider this scenario, I have created a Teacher -> created a Student with mapping to this Teacher -> Updates the Teacher, not the Student. this won't change the mapped id in the student, right?

Comment: I have answered your original question, which, by my estimate, centered around the entity definitions.  If you need help with some JPA workflow you should either edit your question and reveal that problem, or ask a new question.